# Are pickle-able tuple-factories (with names) possible?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle, python-3.9, namedtuple

There are several questions about pickling namedtuples already, however none of the ones I found [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16377215/how-to-pickle-a-namedtuple-instance-correctly) [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677012/python-cant-pickle-type-x-attribute-lookup-failed?noredirect=1&lq=1) [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20143726/understanding-an-issue-with-the-namedtuple-typename-and-pickle-in-python) [[4]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22304815/multiprocessing-objects-with-namedtuple-pickling-error) deals with the case of pickling a namedtuple that is bound on an object instance. Consider the following example

```py
import pickle
from collections import namedtuple


class TupleSplitter:
    r"""Splits a tuple into namedtuple, given by the groups."""

    def __init__(self, groups: dict[str, list[int]]):
        self.groups = groups
        self.group_type = namedtuple("Groups", groups)  # <-- How to replace this?

    def __call__(self, x: tuple) -> tuple:
        return self.group_type(
            **{key: tuple(x[k] for k in group) for key, group in self.groups.items()}
        )


encoder = TupleSplitter({"a": [0, 1, 2], "b": [2, 3, 4]})
encoder((1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))

pickle.dumps(encoder)  # <-- PicklingError: attribute lookup Groups on __main__ failed
```

### Question: Is it possible to have pickle-able tuple-factories with attribute names only known at runtime?

**NOTE: I am not interested in any answers suggesting using a dictionary here, the return value MUST be a subclass of tuple!**

**NOTE: I am not interested in any answers proposing using a dill, cloudpickle or anything of the like. It must work with plain pickle!**

Comment: You'd need to implement the pickling protocol, probably you can just monkey patch the class. You should be able to just implement `__reduce__`, see this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657781/factory-method-pattern-conflicts-with-use-of-multiprocessing-queue

Comment: Although those answers seem convoluted... I'm on my phone right now I'll try to look at this later on my laptop. But check out the pickle docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need two custom picklers, one for the factory and one for the tuples themselves.

This seems to work, but there may be pitfalls. For example, before pickling `TupleSplitter.group_type` and the generated tuples' types are the same; after pickling, they will be different (but equivalent) types. This can be "fixed" by maintaining a registry/cache for `Group`s, but that will have different behaviour in other cases (same type for different splitters with same group names).

If only the factory needs to be pickleable, it should be straightforward (just skip the `_group_pickle` and `copyreg` stuff).

```
import copyreg
import pickle
from collections import namedtuple

def _group_pickle(ntup):
    return (_group_unpickle, (ntup._fields, tuple(ntup)))
def _group_unpickle(groups, tup):
    return namedtuple("Group", groups)(*tup)

class TupleSplitter:
    r"""Splits a tuple into namedtuple, given by the groups."""
    def __init__(self, groups: dict[str, list[int]]):
        self.groups = groups
        self.group_type = namedtuple("Group", groups)
        copyreg.pickle(self.group_type, _group_pickle)

    def __call__(self, x: tuple) -> tuple:
        return self.group_type(
            **{key: tuple(x[k] for k in group) for key, group in self.groups.items()}
        )

    def __reduce__(self):
        return (self._unpickle, (self.groups,))

    @staticmethod
    def _unpickle(groups):
        return TupleSplitter(groups)

encoder = TupleSplitter({"a": [0, 1, 2], "b": [2, 3, 4]})
encoder2 = TupleSplitter({"c": [0, 1, 2], "d": [2, 3, 4]})

print(pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(encoder((1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)))))
print(pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(encoder))((1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)))
print(pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(encoder2((1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)))))
```

->

```
Group(a=(1, 2, 3), b=(3, 4, 5))  # pickled tuple from encoder
Group(a=(1, 2, 3), b=(3, 4, 5))  # tuple from pickled encoder
Group(c=(1, 2, 3), d=(3, 4, 5))  # pickled tuple from encoder2
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, and sorry for the late response. This works, but I guess has the disadvantage that a new, distinct class will be created each time a tuple is unpicked. Though I am not sure if there is any way around that to be honest.

Comment: They can share type, but then you will have to keep a cache or registry of namedtuple types — keyed on tuple-of-fieldnames — to make each field combination a singleton. It is harder to keep the full pre-pickle semantics of different types for different factories, even if they share field names. In that case, the factories and tuples must additionally store some persistent identifier (uuid) to be able to match them.

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative solution, based on [a comment made here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17329487/9318372)

The idea is based on 2 tricks:

1. Classes that are added to `globals` can always be pickled
2. The pickle lookup is performed by `__qualname__` and `__name__` appears to be used as a fallback.

The second one allows us to hide a unique but ugly autogenerated classname.

```py
import pickle
from collections import namedtuple


class TupleSplitter:
    r"""Splits a tuple into namedtuple, given by the groups."""

    def __init__(self, groups: dict[str, list[int]], *, name="Groups"):
        self.groups = groups
        self.tuple = namedtuple(name, groups)

        # create a unique identifier and store it in globals
        self.identifier = f"_{self.tuple.__name__}_{hash(self)}"
        self.tuple.__qualname__ = self.identifier

        if self.identifier in globals():
            raise RuntimeError(f"A class of name '{self.identifier}' exists!!")
        globals()[self.identifier] = self.tuple

    def __call__(self, x: tuple) -> tuple:
        return self.tuple(
            **{key: tuple(x[k] for k in group) for key, group in self.groups.items()}
        )

    def __del__(self):
        """Delete the globals entry when the class instance is deleted."""
        identifier = self.tuple.__qualname__
        if identifier not in globals():
            raise RuntimeError(f"'{identifier}' was already purged!")
        del globals()[identifier]
        del self


encoder = TupleSplitter({"a": [0, 1], "b": [2]})
groups1 = encoder(("foo1", "bar1", "baz1"))
groups2 = encoder(("foo2", "bar2", "baz2"))
pickle1 = pickle.dumps(groups1)
pickle2 = pickle.dumps(groups2)
tuple1 = pickle.loads(pickle1)
tuple2 = pickle.loads(pickle2)
assert type(groups1) == type(groups2)
assert type(tuple1) == type(tuple2)
assert type(tuple1) == type(groups1)
assert tuple1 == groups1
```